# echo \\\$variable_name in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, echo

I came across this syntax in shell script, and not able to comprehend meaning of echo\\ against a variable:

I have a file like this:

data_file:

```
variable1=value1
variable2=value2
```

At command prompt we do like this (i mimicked what is in shell script).

```
$ VARIABLE1=`sh -c ". data_file; echo \\\$variable1"`
```

and when we do $VARIABLE_1, its value is value1.

What i don't understand is importance of \\ after the echo.

If we don't mention these \\ then value of $VARIABLE_1 is blank.

I did google however didn't get proper result, and hence asking here.

Thanks

Comment: There are three '\' not two. like echo \\\

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I am debugging existing shell script, seems it is assiging value of variable1 in file data_file into a variable VARIABLE1. I didn't understand why we have three \ in the echo statement.

Comment: \\ turns into \ when the string is expanded.  Also `\$` turns into `$`  So they are just making a string that says echo $variable1 after expansion.

Comment: What you're doing can be done with: `VARIABLE1=\`sh -c '. ./data_file; echo "$variable1"'\``

Comment: @anubhava: I tried your suggestion, however it is coming blank. I really appreciate your help here, many thanks.

Comment: Typing **`VARIABLE1=\`sh -c '. ./data_file; echo "$variable1"'\`; echo "$VARIABLE1"`** is giving me `value1` using `sh` or `bash`

Comment: I will try one more time. I thank your for your help, time. Thanks a lot